# LinearRegionItem add new contextMenu

Tags: pyqtgraph

For some days now, I am trying to generate a context menu for a LinearRegionItem (to be able to annotate the marked regions). In fact, I successfully created a new class AnnotationItem to overwrite several methods from LinearRegionItem. With contextMenuEvent, I have the possibility to trigger the generation of the context menu, however I am facing to problems:

1.) How do I prevent the default plot menu to be called when using the (in my case) right mouse button
([see default plot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrc8A.png)) without overall deactivating the menu? In the current implementation, the contextMenuEvent method is called, however, the default plot menu appears afterwards.

2.) How do I prevent the new menu from disappearing directly after it is called? [See here for gif.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clslE.gif)

Thank you so much for your support.

Cheers,

Nico

```
class AnnotationItem(LinearRegionItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnnotationItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs, showSize=True)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        print('Method called...')
        cmenu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        test1Act = cmenu.addAction("Test1")
        test2Act = cmenu.addAction("Test2")
        pos = event.screenPos()
        cmenu.popup(QtCore.QPoint(pos.x(), pos.y()))
```

Answer (score 0):

New week, found the solution:
add a `cmenu.exec()` at the end of the contextMenuEvent method and all problems are solved.

Thanks anyway...